# .NET MVC3 Project Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have looked around but cannot find anything that answered this particular question related to file/project structure.

I have an MVC3 site using entity framework. It follows a basic generic repository pattern using StructureMap to handle dependency resolution.

My question is, how do I lay the projects out? taking in mind I may want to expose the database to another application down the track.

Currently I have:

> mySite.Web -- MVC Project also has all the dependency resolution
>
> mySite.Web.Data -- EntityFramwork CodeFirst, Repository pattern
>
> mySite.Web.Tests -- Tests... :-)

Should I be moving my EntityFramwork models to there own project? if so where would things like my EntityContextFactory go?

Thanks

Comment: this is largely subjective, but here's what i do:

App.Domain - business logic (models, contracts)
App.Infra - data/infrastructure related (mapping, repositories)
App.Web.Mvc - front end (controllers, views, IoC)
App.Tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new project called mySite.Domain and possibly create a entities folder in that project and place them in there.

I'd only store entities in the Domain and keep all repositories, your dbcontext and entity contextfactory in your Data project.

Here are some sample projects you could have a look at (credit to authors):

http://myfinance.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/darind/samplemvc

This is largely subjective though.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem - How to setup a new mvc project?
My research and help for other user is: A good structure approach is the **Domain Driven Design** for MVC Architectures.

[good blog post for DDD](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/03/11/domain-driven-design-and-mvc-architectures/)

my new project structure will look something like this:

- Presentation.Web (Controller, Views, ModelViews..)
- Presentation.Web.Utils (Helper and Extensions..)
- Presentation.Web.Tests (Moq..)
- BusinessDomain.Services (Business Service for DI )
- BusinessDomain.Models (EF Models..)
- BusinessDomain.Tests (Moq..)
- CrossCutting.Common (Const, Resources, Exception Msg...)
- Infrastructure.Configuration (IoC Bootstrapper, ApplicationConfiguration,ContainerExtensions..)
- Infrastructure.DataSource  (DbContext, Repositorys..)
- Infrastructure.Tests (Moq..)

Answer (score 1):

No this structure is good.you may move pattern repository to `mySite.Web` or create another class library project for it but it is not necessary.